# How to get value from dropdown list in jsp?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to get the value from a dropdown list in SetRole.jsp from SaveRole.jsp, but it kept return null. Does any one can see where the problem is?

This is the code I wrote:
In SetRole.jsp

```
<form action="SaveRole.jsp">
    <select name = "test">
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b">b</option>
        <option value="c">c</option>
    </select>   
</form>
```

In SaveRole.jsp

```
<%= request.getParameter("test") %>
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    <form action="SaveRole.jsp">
        <select name = "test">
            <option value="a">a</option>
            <option value="b">b</option>
            <option value="c">c</option>
        </select>  
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 

    </form>


<% request.getParameter("test") %>
```

Comment: it still returns null :(

Comment: @mjl690  Add <input type="submit" value="Submit"> in form tag it will work

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="SaveRole.jsp">
  <select name="test">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

in **SaveRole.jsp**

```
request.getParameter("test");
```

This should work!